# Django+gunicorn+nginx site runs perfect when using example.com:8000 but not when using example.com

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn, digital-ocean

I have a site on Digital Ocean VPS.
But I get a bad gateway when accessing `example.com` but not when `example.com:8000`.

Also when visiting the django-admin at `example.com:8000/admin` the default formatting is not coming. I guess nginx is not being able to serve the static content.

Below is the service file for gunicorn:

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/FINlit
ExecStart=/FINlit/venvforfinlit/bin/gunicorn --access-logfile - --workers 3 --bind unix:/FINlit/Finlit.sock Finlit.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

and the nginx config:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name my_ip;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /FINlit;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/FINlit/Finlit.sock;
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: What's the point of the `upstream app_server_wsgiapp` block? You're not proxying anything to it. And what's running on 127.0.0.1:8000?

Comment: Even after removing the block, there's no difference.

Comment: I didn't say it would fix the problem (otherwise I would have made it an answer not a comment), just wondering what it was for. Are you sure gunicorn is running and can write to that socket? Are there any messages in the logs for gunicorn, nginx or systemd?

Comment: Thanks @DanielRoseman, but replacing the IP with the domain name, somehow did the trick.

Comment: I have also edited the config file as per your advice. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After almost searching for a couple of hours, my instincts led me to replace the IP with the domain name in the nginx config and now it works fine.
Actually I don't know, there might be a possibility that something else did the job for me but anyways.